# Integrating a MQTT broker inside server

Tags: rest, client-server, mqtt, messagebroker

I am learning about MQTT brokers, and I have got a question I cannot answer. Is it possible integrate a MQTT broker inside a server that acts as a client in a client/server architecture? - The reason I would need that is in case that this client retrieves data from an API.

I have tried to [depict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM44n.jpg) what I mean. If it is not possible, how would one approach it then, in case the data from the API is needed?

Comment: Thats for sure possible from the technical perspective. This is more question about architecture of your solution, scalability, availbility etc. Questions is if it is really necessary to have it inside the Client? Do you need to customize this mqtt broker somehow? Is it like Client is retreivng data from REST API and publishing it to the broker?

Comment: The client receives data from REST API, which it publishes to the subscribers

Comment: Please use the Stack Overflow service for hosting images, then they can be inlined into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no reason for the broker to be part of the client.

The client receives the data and then publishes it as a message to a separate broker where subscribers receive the message. There is no benefit to combing the two.

Building adapters like this is common practice (it's one of the reasons tools like Node-RED were created)